# Array callback must have exactly two elements

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

form models

```
    {

        //filters search

        if(isset($filters['search']) ? $filters['search'] : false){

            return $query->where('tittle','like','%' . $filters('search') . '%')

            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%' .$filters('search') . '%');

        }

    }
```

and from controller

```
            "posts" => Post::latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get()
```

and i get Array callback must have exactly two elements

i just learning laravel 8 please help me

Answer (score 0):

just change it $filters['search'] not $filters('search')

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your conditional check inside the if block, you are doing extra work there. Rather than using `isset` you can use `empty` This will check if the key exists and it is not null and empty too. So it will be like:

```
     if (!empty($filters['search'])) {
        return $query->where('tittle', 'like', '%'.$filters['search'].'%')
            ->orWhere('body', 'like', '%'.$filters['search'].'%');
    }
```

Also, if you are trying to fetch search request from the request then you should just use `request('search)`. And in the filter method (scope). Are you sure that you need array there since you are passing a single search value, is `request('search)` an array?

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = data_get($filters, 'search', false);
return $query->when(!empty($search), function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('tittle', 'like', "%$search%")
        ->orWhere('body', 'like', "%$search%");
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.